# How to remove the ?tab= in the url

Tags: typescript

I have a page with three sections and each section is represented by a tab. One tab is shown at a time, when a tab is clicked then the other sections are hidden and the selected section is shown.
for example

```
.sidebar
   .sidebar.active(data-tab="-tab1") Tab 1
   .sidebar(data-tab="-tab2")  Tab 2
   .sidebar(data-tab="-tab3")  Tab 3
```

what i wanted to create is that each tab should have its own link so that if it is called in other pages it will redirect to the certain section.

here is what I've done so far,

with this line of code

```
const activeTab = tabs[i].getAttribute('data-tab');
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
url.searchParams.set('tab', activeTab !== null ? activeTab : ''); 
history.pushState(null,'' , url.toString());
```

it results to this,
http://127.0.0.1:8080/sample.html?tab=-tab1

It works just like how I wanted, however what I want to remove the ?tab= in the url
like this,
http://127.0.0.1:8080/sample.html-tab1

Edit:
I have tried to add these lines

```
const baseUrl = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname; 
const activeTab = tabs[i].getAttribute('data-tab');
const url = new URL(baseUrl); 
url.pathname += '/' + activeTab;
history.pushState(null, '', url.toString());
```

the result is this:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/sample.html/tab3

however when I tried to manually type the url it shows error. Unlike with the one with ?tab= even if it is manually typed it will still redirect to that section.

Comment: `sample.html-tab1` would imply you are loading a file with the extension `html-tab1`, which would be very odd (and would take some pretty weird workarounds to make functional) What you have at the moment is more conventional, why exactly do you want to change it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, What did you try to solve your problem? The only solution I can think of would be with URL rewrite in an `.htaccess` file. However, as DBS points out, this is a weird format. Usually to do this kind of trick URL rewriting is made by simulating a subfolder, eg `http://127.0.0.1:8080/sample.html/tab1`, something that is not understood as trying to access a file called `sample.html-tab1`

Comment: i would like to have a custom link for each tab, maybe http://127.0.0.1:8080/sample.html/tab1 is okay. Is it possible or is it ok to have the ?tab= in the url?

Comment: The "classical" way is to use `location.hash` so it looks like `http://127.0.0.1:8080/sample.html#/tab3`

Comment: `http://localhost:8081/admin/master/console/#/my-realm/users/dimava/credentials` is  a good example of using both html and hash routes at once